# Setting defaul state in a reactivejs/redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my current **ReactJS** component, I have to call a REST API and get the JSON. It is done in **componentWillMount**.

I have introduced **Redux** in my app. Where should I make the call now to get the JSON and set as the default state? Is it in **Redux** or my **React** app?

Any example appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to have a configureStore.js file that exports a `configureStore()` function that handles the store setup (initial state, middleware, and enhancers) and returns your store. See the ["real-world" example in the redux repo](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/store/configureStore.prod.js) for an example of this.

In your case, a simple approach would be to request the data from your REST API when your app starts up, and then when you receive the response, call `configureStore(initialState)` (where `initialState` is the data you fetched) and then proceed with the rest of the app setup and initial rendering. This approach will add a little time to your app startup though, because its initialization will be paused while it's waiting for that API response.

Another option would be to just create your store normally (without the prerequisite API fetch), and then make the actual initial state request from your API after your store has been created. When that API response is received, you could dispatch an INITIAL_STATE action, and have reducers ready to handle that. In this approach, you'd probably want some sort of loading indicator in place during this initial fetch, since your app will have rendered or at least started to render during the API request.

If you're doing server rendering, you can just fetch the initial state data from the server side, and attach it to the `window` object of the index.html that you're rendering. See the ["universal" example in the redux repo](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/universal/server/server.js#L69) for an example of this. That'll allow you to simply [grab your initial state from the `window` object when you create your store](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/universal/client/index.js#L8-9).

Answer (score 2):

You'll usually want to dispatch an action from `componentDidMount` (or `Will` depending on your lifecycle constraints). That action will kick off the XHR and usually return either a thunk (redux-thunk) or a promise (redux-promise-middleware). If a thunk, it will be set up to dispatch another action with the results, or with a promise it does that for you, then reduce that state in as per normal and bind it to the component.